# Java bitmask range

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bit

I need to extract an exact range of bits from an existing long, specifically I need bits 51:12 from a 64 bit value.

The value is:

```
0x0000000415B2C01E
```

So the value of bits 51:12 should be:

```
0x0000415B2C
```

I'm a bit confused as to how to actually extract that range, or any range for that matter.  I've been told to simply left shift by 12 (value << 12) to obtain the bits I need, but that gives me the value of:

```
0x415B2C01E000
```

Now I might be completely misunderstanding how bit shifting works, but I can't get my head around how to extract bit ranges.  I've found a lot of existing stuff on it, but I'm even more confused about it all now.

If anyone could help me out, it would certainly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Right shift, not left shift, that will make 51:12 the least significant bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift and mask:

```
answer = value >> 12 & 0xFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: Should be `answer = value >> 12 & 0x0000007FFFFFFFFF;`